# Top admin tool bar not displaying for "Editor" user role

Tags: admin-bar

To handle user role permissions - I decided that not all of 50 users should have Administrative roles - Most of our user are "Editors" and so I switched them from an Administrative role to Editor.

Problem now is that the Editor users don't have access to the top tool bar. (They had access to it when they are an Administrator role).

What I tried so far

- I made sure that " Show Toolbar when viewing site " has been checked.
- I disabled all of the plugins in a staging env until the site crashed.
- Switched to a new theme (and it worked)

Any troubleshooting ideas would be most welcome

Also - Is there any php documentation that pertains to this feature? How would one insure that users have access to the top admin tool bar when developing a theme with php?

Comment: you're sure editors have permission to do anything with the post that's missing the admin bar?

Comment: if this is a third-party theme, this question will be out of scope here. Is it?

Comment: If it worked when you switched theme then there's something in your theme that's causing it. Without being able to see the code (although a full theme audit is well out of scope), the best anyone could offer is to suggest speaking to the theme author.

Comment: "How would one insure that users have access to the top admin tool bar when developing a theme with php?" There's no reason the toolbar would be hidden from just Editors by the theme unless it was deliberately coded to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i found the piece of code causing the issue :

```
function remove_admin_bar() {
```

if (! current_user_can('administrator', 'editor') && !is_admin() && !is_editor()) {
show_admin_bar(false);
}
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

I switched `show_admin_bar(false);`

to

```
show_admin_bar(true);
```